# How to target entities relative to the executor in scoreboard operations?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make an entity execute a scoreboard operation in minecraft 1.9, the entity should set the score of another entity to it selfs score.

Setting up testing environment:

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"setter"}
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"getter"}
/scoreboard objectives add test dummy
/scoreboard players set @e[name=setter] test 111
```

As you can see, `@e[c=1]` executed by `setter` should select himself (this is true for every entity):

```
/execute @e[name=setter] ~ ~ ~ say my name is @e[c=1]
[setter] my name is setter
```

But when using the selector in an scoreboard operation this doesn't work:

```
/execute @e[name=setter] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players operation @e[name=getter] test = @e[c=1] test
No test score for MY-MINECRAFT-NAME found
Failed to execute ...
```

In the scoreboard operation `e[c=1]` seems to target me (`MY-MINECRAFT-NAME`).

Is there any way to achive what I'm trying to do? And why doesn't this work for scoreboard operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `c=1` does create a sender bias, it also has the potential to create a "player" bias, which will attempt to target players first before targeting non-player entities. A player bias is dependent on the command/feature. The only cases where a player bias occurs is with `/scoreboard` commands (not counting `/scoreboard teams join ...` or `/scoreboard players tag ...`) and stored CommandStats.

The solution is to prevent targeting players, such as either with the `type=!Player` parameter:

```
/execute @e[name=setter] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players operation @e[name=getter] test = @e[type=!Player,c=1] test
```

Or targeting the specific type of entity with `@e[type=ArmorStand]`:

```
/execute @e[name=setter] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players operation @e[name=getter] test = @e[type=ArmorStand,c=1] test
```